# Вывод данных в консоль из Firebase-базы

Tags: firebase

Как вывести из базы данных на скрине значение balance в консоль?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ref.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('balance').on("value",
function(snapshot) {
  console.log('snapshot.val()); // 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял что подпапки **Users** это **Uid**?
Если нужен баланс по одному пользователю - 
Код:

```
var users = new Firebase("https://<yourappname>.firebaseio.com/users");    
var authData = users.getAuth();
var usersRef = ref.child("users/" + authData.uid + "/balance");
usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
var data = snapshot.val();
console.log(data);
});
```

А вот если для всех пользователей, нужно делать цикл, который будет перебирать UID, менять usersRef, и таким образом вытаскивать информацию.